# Which questions about programming tools are allowed?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15604413/gui-for-creating-azure-database-tables) has been closed as off-topic with the displayed reason being:

> This question is seeking recommendations for books, tools, software libraries, and more.

The [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) says Stack Overflow is the right place to ask for **software tools commonly used by programmers**.

The question doesn't seem to *only* be a please-recommend-software type; in my opinion, it's more about Visual Studio capabilities and the differences between the tools for Azure SQL databases and the tools for on-premises SQL Server databases.

So, could someone clarify:

- *which* questions about programming tools are allowed
- why this question was closed
- how one should ask this question so it's not closed as off-topic

Comment: The litmus test for a question like that is "will it attract spam?". It did.  Probably what inspired Chris to close it, eventually.

Answer (score 21):

Questions about how to use a tool used by a programmer to achieve a well-defined goal are allowed.

This question was closed because it read as a shopping question (but we've seen worse)

> *Does anybody know of a GUI based tool for creating and modifying data table schemas?*

Instead it should have asked (to stay on the safe side):

> *How do I create and modify data tables for my SQL Azure Databases in Visual Studio 2012 after the feature `Add New Table / Open Table Definition` that existed in VS2010 is gone?*

The answers could recommend a tool (!) or have a solution in the context of VS2012 or provide a script as suggested by the OP.

Comment: The OP also asked "Does Visual Studio 2012 support this?", so it's clearly not only a "please recommend a tool" question.

Comment: I know. I'm not saying it **is** a recommend a tool question.

Comment: @ken2k the OP asked *two* questions.  One was a recommendation, one was a bit about visual studio. This could lead some votes to "too broad" and others to "recommend" - both are correct.

Comment: So this means "How do I do X?" is a valid question, assuming they've constrained it narrowly enough to not be very broad.  So instead of "What is a tool for exporting Excel files?" I could ask "How can I export the results of a query to Excel?  I'm fine with an answer that leverages a library not part of the base .NET Framework."  **Do you think this is a valid question?** I note the extra loosening of constraints, as often some questions assume you are asking for a solution that uses core language/framework. E.g. when people ask a javascript question, answers get downvoted if they use jQuery.

Comment: @AaronLS Only if that question also shows what has been tried.

Comment: @rene You mean along the lines of when people comment "What is the problem? What have you tried?"  Maybe I don't have a problem. Maybe I've come up with a solution that works.  But due to my ignorance of a tool or approach, it is probably horrible.  If I'm using python for the first time I know there's probably a couple common approaches to database access, but without experience I have to guess between what I find in google. **Does that mean I'm not allowed to tap the community for what is better?**

Comment: @rene  If I show working code, it's going to be moved to code review, where it will likely only be answered in the context of the tool/approach I'm using.  If I am new to C# and followed some tutorial that uses ADO.NET and post some ADO.NET code asking if there's a better approach, it gets moved to Code Review because "there isn't a problem"(the SO go to phrase), where it is less likely that someone would suggest that "ADO.NET is rarely used in new projects, and an ORM is often used instead".

Comment: @rene The "what have you tried" only applies to a problem IMO, and the on-topic guide says "a specific programming problem, **or** [...] software tools commonly used by programmers; and is a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development".

Comment: I tried to answer the specific question. There is a ton of subtleties and opinions on on-topic-ness. I'm not saying that I disagree with any of your points but I'm not sure how to best capture them in my answer. Can you give your thought on that?

Answer (score 11):

You said:

> The help center says SO is the right place to ask for software tools
>   commonly used by programmers.

That's not all it says, you have to read the entire thing really.

It also states:

> - software tools commonly used by programmers; and is
> - a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development

It also states:

> **Some questions are still off-topic, even if they fit into one of the
>   categories listed above:**
>
> 4. Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software
>      library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack
>      Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam.
>      Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve
>      it.

---

The simple fact is, questions asking "How do I" or "What software is best for.." bring *opinionated* answers.

### As for your exact question

It was closed because it *was* asking for a recommendation!

Quote the question:

> **Does anybody know of** a GUI based tool for creating and modifying data
>   table schemas?

The following was arguably legit:

> Does Visual Studio 2012 support this?

Although it makes for a very *weak* question as one can look at the software manual/guide/FAQ/Google and find this info.

The question simply has "can you recommend".
It's not on topic for this site as per the rules, even if it's just because part of the question, it is still off topic and will attract:

1. I use XYZ because it does yadda
2. Oh, no, don't use XYZ, because ABC is better it does blah etc
3. I don't use XYZ because it's not good as it [etc], I sometimes use
   ABC because it can [etc], but I primarily use ...

There is no clear cut answer to this and attracts opinion, and opinion is not fact - the answers are effectively "advice", and not simply *factually correct*.

Again, this is a good discussion, and we all get to know what each other likes and why, which is great.
But the rules are clear, and such things are not allowed here.