# Are questions about IDE crashes on-topic?

Tags: support, scope

Today I stumbled across [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34343434/vs-2015-keeps-crashing-at-random) (no obligatory screenshot (*gasp!*) as the question is quite long) about Visual Studio 2015 crashing 'at random'.

My initial thought was that it is off-topic as the question asks us to 'debug Microsoft's code' ([as Clifford put it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34343434/vs-2015-keeps-crashing-at-random#comment56430044_34343434)), and that such a question would be far better suited to Super User. However Stack Overflow *does* allow questions about 'programming tools':

> software tools commonly used by programmers... … then you’re in the right place to ask your question!

Visual Studio *is* a programming tool, and so a question asking us to help fix a crash with one could be seen as on-topic.

[Which questions about programming tools are allowed?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/288832/which-questions-about-programming-tools-are-allowed) states this:

> Questions about how to use a tool used by a programmer to achieve a well-defined goal are allowed.

Is this question about how to use Visual Studio to achieve a well-defined goal? *Not really.*

I also [asked about this on the SOCVR](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/27612782#27612782), and the general consensus there was that the question *is* on-topic, but there also seems to be the small feeling of doubt there.

Essentially when broken down, this question is asking 'how do I stop this program from crashing?'. Maybe on-topic if it was the OP's own program, but it's not.

Are questions about fixing program crashes with IDEs on-topic for Stack Overflow?

Might also mention that the answer for this type of question is almost always going to be '*reset the IDE's settings, otherwise reinstall it*'.

Comment: I wouldn't call this "debugging program crashes" so much as finding workarounds for them.

Comment: All I can say is that some tools, like a few I use, need a few "eyes" for that question on SO (first) before they would go to Superuser. Even if it is a *crash*

Comment: Kind of on the fence here. Visual Studio is used very widely by the SO community. However, Super User generally deals with fixing issues from installed programs. I am not sure why you asked about "debugging ide" though, because that is most certainly not what is going on here - no one is stepping through the visual studio source code. So basically, yes, questions about IDE source code are on topic. And maybe, *troubleshooting* highly used IDE's are on topic for SO.

Comment: @TravisJ Changed the 'debugging' stance to 'fix crashes'.

Comment: @cybermonkey - I think that is a good discussion to have. I would like to see where other people in the community stand on this topic. Personally, I don't mind them as long as they are properly formed and not an XY problem. However, I may not be in the majority.

Comment: The question is clearly on-topic.  Whether it's answerable or not on a Q&A site is another issue entirely.  I've seen forum posts like this that are nothing but noise.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I disagree that it is 'clearly on-topic', because if it was I wouldn't be asking for clarification.

Comment: **To clarify:** The subject matter of the question is within the site scope, but the question itself is probably Too Broad.  There's no MCVE provided, and it would be difficult (if not impossible) to reproduce the OP's exact operating environment for troubleshooting purposes.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Wouldn't that mean the answer to my (Meta) question as being 'questions about IDE crashes are too broad to be answered in the Stack Exchange Q&A format'?

Comment: Yes, I believe I just said that.

Comment: @RobertHarvey there's no real way to fix this other than by going nuclear.  I've seen this question so many times I recently created a canonical for the only true solution--reinstall. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34095134/visual-studio-is-acting-weird-how-do-i-fix-this