# How to handle a question about IDE Settings/Plugins in review process?

Tags: support, review-queues, specific-question

I got a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/13137767) where the questioner asks for help with his IDE. So my question is kinda related to this similar [question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/312790/are-questions-about-ide-crashes-on-topic).

I doubt that he will find in another stack site an answer, because Stackoverflow or Programmers are the only ones that use these IDEs thought.

So I guess this question is off-topic. But I do not know to which topic such questions belong to.

**Could you tell me a stack where this questioner can ask his IDE question or is stackoverflow the right place for it?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this question (even when properly worded) is not on-topic on any Stack Exchange site. It looks like (but it's unclear at the moment) that the OP is asking for a tutorial to achieve something in their IDE, and that is [off-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic):

> 4. Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Note that questions about IDEs *can* be on-topic; the same page from the help center mentions

> software tools commonly used by programmers

as one of the possible question topics.

Comment: Okay - I think he just asks if there is any and how to install them if there is one. But beside this question - if someone askes how to use debugging in an IDE and even provides an example what he has tried so far - to which stack would this belong to?

Comment: @jurik specific questions about development tools actually are on-topic on SO.

Comment: @Gimby As long as they are part of a practical programming process. *"How to change the skin to my IDE"* isn't really our cup of tea, unless that's part of programming "my program requires the skin of the IDE to be dark".