# "Seeking recommendations for tools” rule conflict with “Consiseness/Readability" rule

Tags: discussion, scope, close-reasons

My question was flagged for seeking a recommendation on tools: [Recommended NodeJs http client library to reduce serverless coldstart?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64748515/recommended-nodejs-http-client-library-to-reduce-serverless-coldstart)

The question wasn't a lib or ad bait. The key idea is to know whether or not a standard (free) node library is more suitable for this kind of situation than external (free) modules. It's not well-documented and relies more on the internal behavior of cloud providers (who do answer on SO) and searching on the subject is really hard (conflicting with other thematics).

Is there any insight on why this rule has been set?
[In another meta question the answer says that "best" is subjective](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/211271/261295). I don't understand how good practice reducing coldstart boot time would be subjective?

The whole point of SO was to help people **with concrete cases**, because it makes questions both easy to understand and easy to be found, and if the case isn't exactly the same, it turns to give so much information that isn't provided by documentation, even on the simplest questions, **and I can't see why would that would harm SO?**

I could write my question in a way that mentions none of the type of modules, but it would become really hard to understand, and nobody would find it on Google... and then what's the point?

Comment: If you are looking for a software/libraries recommendation try [softwarerecs.se].

Comment: What is the "Consiseness/Readability rule" you refer to in the title?

Comment: That specific question will be much more useful if you turn it into a problem: *I use this code with lib fubar which shows a cold start-up time of 6 to 8 seconds. I've done x and y already. What other options do I have to get it down to 3 seconds? I'm open for switching to a different library*. Answers will either solve your problem, explain that your way of measuring is wrong or offer a more performant lib/ implementation. Future visitors will learn how to measure/diagnose start-up time and get a few alternatives.

Comment: @rene Agree on that, it ll make the question  harder to seek if "fubar" isnt a common library but i agree it ll look more like genuine question rather than an advice request.

Comment: @HereticMonkey Sorry but no, i am maybe unclear but im not looking for name, but for approach.

Comment: @rene That could be added as an answer.

Comment: @EJoshuaS-ReinstateMonica no it's not i m not looking for a library. I m really sorry my english is really bad but this is not my intention.

Comment: The title of your question is literally "**Recommended** NodeJs http client **library** to reduce serverless coldstart?" If you're not looking for someone to recommend a library, that is a very poor choice of title. A better title might be "How can I reduce serverless coldstart using Node.js HTTP client?" if you are looking for approaches.

Comment: The second answer to the suggested duplicate addresses this question nicely, I think. Voted accordingly.

Comment: @gnat Sorry but no, the whole answer is about how the question didn't provide probleme/criteria (i do mention it: coldstart). I think the whole probleme in my case was the misleading title.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That specific question will be much more useful if you turn it into a problem:

*I use this code with lib fubar which shows a cold start-up time of 6 to 8 seconds. I've done x and y already. What other options do I have to get it down to 3 seconds? I'm open for switching to a different library.*

Answers will either solve your problem, explain that your way of measuring is wrong or offer a more performant lib/ implementation.

Future visitors will learn how to measure/diagnose start-up time and get a few alternatives.

I also recommend my previous work on the same topic:

- [Where can I ask programming related questions about if there is a tool for doing task X?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/400684)
- [Which questions about programming tools are allowed?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/288832)

Answer (score 2):

This is off-topic because [real questions have answers, not items or ideas or opinions.](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/01/17/real-questions-have-answers/) This question is soliciting opinions, not facts.

Comment: But measuring time isn't an opinion? I really don't understand...

Comment: @AnthonyBobenrieth "Which library should I use?" is inviting opinions, not facts.

Comment: You mean that the title imply opinion? Even if i mention " to reduce serverless coldstart?". Which.... is ... time...

Comment: @AnthonyBobenrieth The purpose of the library you're asking for recommendations of doesn't matter. It's the recommendation.